# Cubes in cube puzzle

Tags: geometry

It can be easily shown that a square may be cut in any number of (not necessarily same-sized) squares, except in 2, 3 or 5 squares. Are there any results regarding the same question for cubes? Is there a maximum number n without a cube-cutting solution?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is 47. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeDissection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeDissection.html) seems to give an answer of $47$ with an argument to show why.

Comment: I couldn't find good results in higher dimensions and didn't have time to use the method suggested here.